# Error Script Connection SQL SERVER 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem connecting to SQL Server Express 2005 from Visual Studio 2008.

This is the connection string...

```
Public connect As New SqlConnection( _
    "Data Source=MERSI_IT_04\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MERSIFAM;
    Integrated Security=True")
```

When running locally the connection completes successfully, however when the client running the script there is a connection error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Client running connection were - in their environment? Also, is this an ASP.NET, WinForm or other application? And finally seeing actual error message would help too. As well as line of code that causes it

Comment: winform yuriy galanter

Comment: did you open the connection?
connect.Open()?

Comment: yes iceheaven.. connect.open and connect.close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most create one connection with UserName and Password.

And set `SQL Server authentication` on mix mode.

or you can use `Windows authentication` if you use Active Directory and all client are part of domain .

For create a `Connection String` in mix mode use this

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

and en total you can see this link : [http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)